# Finding the language of a given CFG

Tags: automata, context-free

I'm trying to find the language of the given CFG
$S \to aB \mid bA \mid a \\ A \to bAA \mid aS \\ B \to aBB \mid bS$
I understand that the productions $S \to aB, S \to bA, A \to aS$ and $B \to bS$, correspond to the language where the number of a's are equal to the number of b's, but how do I interpret the other productions? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: For starters, the productions you think correspond to the language of $w$ with $\#_a(w)=\#_b(w)$, is incorrect. Actually, it corresponds to the language of the regex $(ab+ba)^*$

Comment: @nirshahar and what about the other productions?